# @font-face with less mixin and unified styles

Tags: less, font-face

Having issues with multiple .less files importing @font-face custom fonts which are local.

**OPTION 1 - Doesn't work**

@font-face is generated with .less in a mixin file called font.less one directory above.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'custom-font';
  src: 
  url("../fonts/client1/custom-font.woff2") format("woff2"), 
  url("../fonts/client1/custom-font.woff") format("woff")
  }
```

The font-family is defined in another file or the can be the same mixin file.

```
@font_family_123: 'custom-font', cursive;
```

The .woff files are nested outside of scripts in correct path.  I can also add google fonts and other hosted .woof files fine with this method.  I have used relative and absolute paths, makes no difference..

**OPTION 2 - Does work**

If I was to include my `@font-face and @font-family` in a base style like `"styles_default.less"` everything works as expected and loads fine. Super simple.. Is there some way to separate when working with large amounts of custom fonts or perhaps this is not supported?

BTW using less-rhino 1.7.5

Best-

Comment: What’s the question? I didn’t get what you want to achieve.

Comment: sure, using import for @font-face in less in separate .less files for adding custom web fonts files.  This doesn't seem to be achievable.   Thought others might have encountered..  Thought the strength of .less is compartmentalized importing like using mixins.  This is not the case here.  Thanks

Comment: Die you checked the compiles `css`? Does the compiler throws an error? Can you post the content of your `less` files?

Comment: sure, I checked the nested fonts.less where all the mixin files live.   w/ declaration so it is correct but it is not parsed when compiled into CSS.  The path works fine if it is in the scripts folder like everything else...

Comment: Sorry if this is cryptic but would assume many people using less have the less files and then a nested directory with variable files for mixins, colors, fonts, etc...   that worked fine until using @font-face which doesn't work in the nested folder

Comment: I use `less` for my projects, and defined `@font-face` as i needed. Never had the problem you mentioned. Maybe the problem is with the file inclusion or how you used the mixins. That’s why i asked you to post your relevant code and file structure.

Comment: thanks, it is quite a bit of code.. appreciate your assistance-

Comment: No problem, take your time to post it.